# perl get the path of a module inside the module?

Tags: perl

I have a perl module `/x/y/z/test.pm`. Inside this module, I want to read a config file `/x/y/z/test.config`. Yet, I am including my module from `/a/b/c/mymain.pl`. How can I get `/x/y/z/` to build the path for `/x/y/z/test.config` in `/x/y/z/test.pm`?

Thanks,

Comment: You might find the `FindBin` core module helpful. See [this perldoc link](http://perldoc.perl.org/FindBin.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK `FindBin` will show `mymain.pl` (and it might have been used in other modules, then the first invocation will win). Try [__FILE__](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/__FILE__.html):

```
my $path = __FILE__;
$path =~ s/pm$/config/;
```